# grammar / meaning Does “treating” in the example sentence mean “because he treats” or “and at the same he is treating” or just “and he treats”?

Tags: meaning, grammar

(“treating”) “He takes in sinners and eats meals with them, treating them like old friends…!”

And does “verb + ing” in the following examples belong to one of the three cases in the title question? Or other meanings?

1. (fearing, knowing) He enfolds us with His arms, never fearing that He will become unclean; but knowing that we will become clean!
2. (having) He is accurate with the longer clubs in his bag, having learned how to manage his normal 'fade' ball flight.
3. (sipping, taking) Follow the direction of ushers to approach the Communion rail, kneel to receive the bread and wine, sipping from the common cup, or taking an individual glass of wine or grape juice.
4. (baptizing) Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit,

Comment: I'd say that the closest paraphrase is '“He takes in sinners and eats meals with them: [in so doing,] he is treating them like old friends…!” It's virtually a reformulatory expression, though with explanation. (1) certainly adds further information about the situation.(2) adds explanatory detail. (3) adds further instructions. (4) is probably part reformulatory, part focusing on a specific within the general instruction.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer would be **and he treats.**

The definition of *treating* used here is "behave toward or deal with in a certain way."

He is behaving toward the sinners in a way that you would treat old friends.